# Tooltip for column headers in a tabular report in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I want to display some tooltips when the user hovers on the column headers.
This way they can know what logic is applied on  a particular column.
Is there a workaround to it because I know it wont work directly in Tableau.

Any workaround suggestions would be highly appreciable.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround,

Rename the dimension with name appended with caluclation so that when you hover on the header then on tooltip you can see both name and calculation and on the sheet make sure that you limit the size of the header to show only name, So that on sheet you can see only name and on tooltip you can see name and calculation.

Comment: Hi Srikanth, some columns are so big, we cannot keep them small in width. So in that case i think everything will be visible

Comment: @Kapil Lehar... I didn't mean to squeez the columns but adjust the width so that only colimn name is visible and formula doesn't visible